# Common factor of 2 terms ( matrices)

Tags: matrices

I have this terms (AXB+X), where A,B, and X are matrices.

How can I take matrix X as a common factor from these 2 terms.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot, except if X commutes with A or B.

Comment: @Lelouch But you don't know it "a priori"... moreover, it is very unlikely in general that such a commutation is true. In fact you can find such a factorization in an extended sense using Kronecker product (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly. But it is possible in a certain way if you use **Kronecker product** transformation of expression $\mathbf {AXB+X}$. More precisely, you will be able to factor out not $\mathbf{X}$ but $\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf {X})$ in the following form that I borrow from the excellent Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) on the Kronecker product:

$$\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {AXB+X} )=\displaystyle \underbrace{\left(\mathbf {B} ^{\textsf {T}}\otimes \mathbf {A} \right)}_K \,\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {X} )+\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {X} )$$

where $K$ is a "huge" $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix (if your matrices are $n \times n$) and $\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {X} )$ is the $n^2 \times 1$ column vector obtained by "piling up" all the columns of $\mathbf {X} $.

For concrete examples, see this [MSc Thesis](https://digitalcommons.unf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1025&context=etd).